# What was the reason for extending NATO in the 1990s?

Tags: united-states, russian-federation, history, nato

I know there are questions that might sound similar, but this is a completely different one. Firstly, I am using the word *extending* and not *expanding*. Secondly, the question is limited to a time period long before 2008 and even before Putin came to power.

At the beginning of the 1990s, the Cold War was officially over, there was no Warsaw Pact and even no USSR was there to threaten NATO. The new Russian government was relative pro-Western, the most pro-Western government in Russia ever. There was no anti-Western propaganda in Russian media, sometimes even the opposite was the case. Thus, no real threat from Russia was expected at that time. It was also clear that extending NATO would change the situation and bring back confrontation. Some people in the Clinton Administration convinced him to postpone the NATO extension at least until after the presidential election in Russia in order to prevent anti-Western candidate from winning. While the arguments against that extension are clear, which ones were for supporting it? People like New York Democrat Daniel Patrick Moynihan and George Kennan have warned that extension of NATO can have bad cosequences.

In 1997, even before Americans learned about Vladimir Putin, 50 former senators wrote a [letter to President Bill Clinton](https://www.armscontrol.org/act/1997-06/arms-control-today/opposition-nato-expansion) against the expansion of the alliance, calling it a political mistake of "historic proportions."

Richard Nixon confirmed that the new Russian government was relative pro-Western:

> Yeltsin is the most pro-Western leader in the history of Russia...
> Whatever its shortcomings, the alternative to the new despotism will
> be much worse

At least acording to an article in german press there was a promis to not extend NATO to the east as can be seen [here](https://www.sott.net/article/464659-Der-Spiegel-confirms-that-NATO-deceived-Russia-when-they-promised-to-not-to-expand-its-border-east?ysclid=l5pf1e5t3d37866123). At least Russia sees the document mentioned in that article as such promis.

So here [a reference](https://www.dw.com/en/nato-why-russia-has-a-problem-with-its-eastward-expansion/a-60891681) to a credible source about the claim that extending NATO would change the situation and bring back confrontation.

The question is refering only to reasons from core NATO countries, specially USA, and not the new members from East Europe, as their reasons are very clear.

Here some references about a discusion which was led in the 1990s in US:

https://newrepublic.com/article/165562/nato-critics-predicted-russia-putin-belligerence-ukraine

https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2022/feb/28/nato-expansion-war-russia-ukraine

https://www.rferl.org/a/1088215.html

https://www.vox.com/22900113/nato-ukraine-russia-crisis-clinton-expansion

https://patrickarmstrong.ca/2016/02/14/george-kennan-on-nato-expansion

https://www.moonofalabama.org/2014/03/george-f-kennans-prediction-on-nato-expansion-was-right.html

Comment: " the most pro-western government in Russia ever. " : A debatable claim... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catherine_the_Great

Comment: "It was also clear that extending NATO would change the situation and bring back the confrontation." citation needed

Comment: @RedSonja The citation your requested: [Joe Biden in 1997 warning of Russian hostility if NATO expands](https://www.newsweek.com/joe-biden-resurfaced-clip-russia-baltic-states-1997-video-1685864)

Comment: @Evargalo I think in case of Catherine II we are not talking about the same Russia... neither about the same Europe - she made war to some European countries and was great friends with others - notably, she took part in [the partitions of Poland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partitions_of_Poland).

Comment: "First I am using the word extending and not expanding" - as you appear to be making this a key point of your question, can you clarify, in the context of NATO, what you see as the meanings of "extend" vs "expand"?

Comment: @JBentley To be honest I personally not seeing any big diferences, but it seames like the word expanding in this context is seen as biased.

Comment: You specifically said that your question is a "completely different one" and that one of the reasons is that it is about extending rather than expanding (you also made a point of it in the comments [here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/73273/6764)). Now you're saying there is no big difference. I think you need to clarify this as it makes your question confusing - the reader is told that your question is different somehow, but it's not clear how.

Comment: @JBentley I was talking about the meaning of the word itself, nobody for example is seeing expansion of the universe as something bad.

Comment: Yes, but in what way does it *change* the question from one about NATO expansion?

Comment: @JBentley It looks like some people understand expansion as invasion and this is defenetly not what the question is about. I am not saing that NATO has forced the counties to join it.

Comment: Wasn’t the enlargement of NATO, after the dismantling of the Soviet Union and Communism, a bit like kicking somebody who has already been knocked to the ground? Could the enlargement be due to that the Americans feared Russia more than they did the Soviet Union? If so, the Cold War did not end in 1991, but was instead intensified.

Comment: “When Michail Gorbachev, the leader of the former Soviet Union, capitulated in 1991, he requested from the western allies a promise that they would not expand NATO beyond Berlin, as a condition for allowing the unification of east and west Germany. This was confirmed by the US Secretary of State James Baker, with the now famous words, “NATO will not move an inch beyond Berlin”. Documents to that extent are available in the Berlin War Museum.” (New Dawn; vol 16, no 3)

Comment: @Constantthin It was 1990 and not 1991. There was no capitulation and the promise by Baker was never brought to paper. The rest is a known fact.

Comment: "What's the difference between an oral and written contract?
The main difference between an oral contract and a written contract is that it is more difficult to prove the existence of an oral contract. Since an oral agreement is not written, the existence of the terms must be proved by the memory of the parties and other evidence."

Comment: "In May 1990, Soviet Union's reformist leader Mikhail Gorbachev visited the U.S. for talks with President Bush; there, he agreed to allow a reunified Germany to be a part of NATO. He later revealed that he had agreed to do so because James Baker promised that NATO troops would not be posted to eastern Germany and that the military alliance would not expand into Eastern Europe. Privately, Bush ignored Baker's assurances and later pushed for NATO's eastwards expansion". (James Baker:Wikipedia)

Comment: @RedSonja Have added some references which should contain some citations.

Comment: @Trilarion Have added many citations.

Comment: Cool. That increases the quality of the question. Now add a summary of what is in the citations and how that already answers or not answers the question. Adding citations is only half of doing research.

Comment: @Trilarion What exactly you mean by summary? If the citations would answer the question, would put them in a separate answer post.

Comment: I mean that initially I noticed a lack of research and asked you to provide prior existing information on that topic. Because it's such a popular topic it's extremely unlikely that you are the first one to come up with this question. You provided links but this is not sufficient for this task. You actually have to kind of read them and say where and how they answer your question already. Chances are high your question is already answered and wouldn't be needed to be asked here. Your question may then need to be reformulated to go beyond what is already known.

Comment: @Trilarion No there are defenetly no aswers in that links.

Comment: OK, then you don't need to summarize them. But are you sure there isn't really any answer in these links? Sometimes even "nobody knows" can be an answer to a question.

Comment: @Trilarion There is even an acepted answer, but it has nothing to do with my links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are already good answers so far, but they seem to have left out the [Wolfowitz Doctrine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfowitz_Doctrine).  The answers by users '[Allure](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/73261/8398)' and '[Fizz](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/73260/8398)' help to contextualise the statements of the era, but we have to keep in mind that these are public statements.  The Wolfowitz doctrine was not intended for the public, it was internal documentation by US policy makers.

America's primary objective, then and now, has been to prevent the emergence of competition.  It is important to explore the psychology involved in this design, most clearly stated in the first draft of the 'Wolfowitz Doctrine', which was leaked to the press in 1992.  The document was hastily redrafted after public criticism.  Three key components of the document's unedited draft are worth examination (emphasis my own).

Regarding superpower status:

> "Our first objective is to prevent the re-emergence of a new rival,
> either on the territory of the former Soviet Union or elsewhere, that
> poses a threat on the order of that posed formerly by the Soviet
> Union. **This is a dominant consideration underlying the new regional
> defense strategy** and requires that we endeavor to prevent any hostile
> power from dominating a region whose resources would, under
> consolidated control, be sufficient to generate global power."

Regarding primacy:

> "The U.S. must show the leadership necessary to establish and protect
> a new order that holds the promise of convincing potential competitors
> that they need not aspire to a greater role or pursue a more
> aggressive posture to protect their legitimate interests. In
> non-defense areas, we must account sufficiently for the interests of
> the advanced industrial nations **to discourage them from challenging
> our leadership** or seeking to overturn the established political and
> economic order. We must maintain the mechanism for deterring potential
> competitors from even aspiring to a larger regional or global role."

Regarding unilateralism:

> "Like the coalition that opposed Iraqi aggression, we should expect
> future coalitions to be ad hoc assemblies, often not lasting beyond
> the crisis being confronted, and in many cases carrying only general
> agreement over the objectives to be accomplished. Nevertheless, the
> sense that the world order is ultimately backed by the U.S. will be an
> important stabilizing factor."

These objectives cast the world as a zero sum competition for singular domination, and so exclude any possibility of equal partnership.  During Trump's presidency many Americans unironically complained that his perspective was unreasonably black and white, with winners and losers and nobody in between.  And yet this mentality has been central to the foreign policy of every American administration since (at least) 1992.  There has been no meaningful change in American thought since then, even though this strategy has been rebranded multiple times; the 'Wolfowitz Doctrine', the 'Bush Doctrine', and then 'America First'.

In 1990 Michal Gorbachev wanted to test American claims that NATO was not just an anti-Russian club, and [asked to join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russia%E2%80%93NATO_relations).

> "You say that NATO is not directed against us, that it is simply a
> security structure that is adapting to new realities. Therefore, we
> propose to join NATO."

US Secretary of State James Baker snubbed the proposal as a "dream".  This contempt set the stage for the gradual deterioration of European security.  The American government at this point was in a euphoric state, believing themselves the winners of the Cold War, and saw no point in establishing alliances where America would be anyone's equal, much less the Russians they had allegedly defeated.  America didn't want the post-Soviet world to be a new era of international cooperation between equals, they engineered global politics to secure uncontested supremacy.  This coincided with others factors named in the other answers.

Answer (score 35):

I'll quote this verbatim from an [answer](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/59059/how-did-western-leaders-justify-natos-eastwards-expansion-after-promising-the-s/68743#68743) I wrote on History.SE. The explanation is by Bill Clinton - American president during the expansion.

> American President Bill Clinton, who was President during the biggest phase of NATO expansion, wrote an article today [April 7, 2022] on [why he expanded NATO](https://www.theatlantic.com/ideas/archive/2022/04/bill-clinton-nato-expansion-ukraine/629499/).
>
> Clinton says he wanted to work for the best but prepare for the worst. He writes that he viewed renewed conflict as a possibility, but one that would depend more on Russia than on NATO. In particular, if Russia were to stay on the path of democracy and cooperation, then there'd be no problem, but if Russia were to become more authoritarian and imperialist, a bigger NATO would bolster Europe's security.
>
> Clinton further says that he tried very hard to help Russia become a democracy. He says he offered money for Yeltsin to pull Russian soldiers back from the Baltic states, let Russia join the Partnership for Peace program with NATO, allowed Russia to join peacekeeping efforts in Bosnia and Kosovo, and supported Russia's entry into the G7. He also says that they had an agreement with Russia to pull NATO & Russian forces back from borders, but Putin declined to go ahead with the plan when he became president.
>
> Clinton says that NATO expansion was very successful, since it provided peace and security to Europe for more than two decades. He further says it has provided prosperity by increasing GDP per capita (naming the Czech Repulic, Hungary, and Poland as examples), and that the prospect of NATO membership is what stopped some Eastern European countries from fighting over old disputes.
>
> Finally, Clinton says that Russia's invasion of Ukraine proves that his policy of NATO expansion was the right one, and that the invasion was not about NATO but about Ukraine's shift towards democracy which threatens Putin's authoritarian rule. He says that if NATO hadn't expanded, the war wouldn't be in Ukraine, it would be in central Europe (East Germany).
>
> Interpret as you will.

Comment: "Clinton, who was President during the biggest phase of NATO expansion": surely not by number of countries. That was in 2004 when Clinton was not president anymore, when 7 countries were admitted. In 1999 only 3 countries were, albeit their area was sizeable due to Poland.

Comment: @Fizz maybe, but Clinton set those plans to expand NATO into motion.

Comment: A politician explaining his actions is not a trustworthy source. Aside from general trust issues with politicians, don't forget that he is party to a ton of highly secretive information that he can't share, even after his presidency is over.

Comment: @Tom That may be true, but we can generally only answer questions here based on what was actually reported. Anything else would be speculation and opinion.

Comment: @Tom True. Clinton even buys the slogan western powers are trying to sell the world that Putin "is not afraid of NATO, but of a democratical Ukraine". According to the West, neither Kravchuck, Kuchma, Yushchenko or Yanukovich were elected democratically and democracy only started there with the first president that got the office via violence: Poroshenko and his figurehead Turchynov. Go figure.

Comment: @Rekesoft "According to the West, neither Kravchuk, Kuchma, Yushchenko, or Yanukovich were elected democratically". That's quite a bold statement. Provide some proof, please cause it sounds like propaganda. I've never heard of the US saying that. Definitely not about Yushchenko and Kravchuk.

Comment: @Igor Ukraine has been a democracy since its independence from USSR. Through the 90s, and the early 2000's it didn't look that Russia was afraid of a democratic Ukraine. Russia hostility towards Ukraine started with the first non-democratically elected president, which runs contrary to all western propaganda. That is, unless you consider that neither Kravchuck, Kuchma, Yushenko or Yanukovich were democratically elected.

Answer (score 24):

> So no real threat from Russia was expected at that time.

Governments can change. This issue was mentioned as such in this regard by [then Deputy Secretary of State] Strobe Talbott, [in 1995](https://books.google.com/books?id=RW_imaOZgq8C&pg=PA94):

> among the contingencies for which NATO must be prepared is that Russia will abandon democracy and return to the threatening patterns of international behavior that have sometimes characterized its history, particularly during the Soviet period.

I remember the West being freaked out by Zyuganov possibly winning the elections in the 1990s, for instance. At least nowadays, there's hardly any difference between Zyuganov's [positions](https://www.peoplesworld.org/article/russian-communist-leader-the-west-is-backing-fascists-and-using-ukraine/) and Putin's, when it comes to foreign affairs, so those fears were probably not entirely unjustified. Also, an internal 1996 document of the CPRF shows that they were actively focusing on attracting the nationalist [Zhirinovsy camp] votes, even back then. This is one of the reasons why he ran as a candidate of the Bloc of National-Patriotic Forces of Russia, instead of the CPRF. [And](https://www.academia.edu/4836559/In_pursuit_of_the_Russian_presidency_Why_and_how_Yeltsin_won_the_1996_presidential_election) more explicitly:

> Zyuganov platform was also composed with the nationalist voters in mind. Even though the
> communists were by far the most dominant force within the alliance, nationalist themes
> dominated its program. It elaborated in great detail all the key ideas the Russian nationalists had
> been articulating for years.  [...] It accused Yeltsin of the destruction of the USSR and
> the abandonment 25 million of ethnic Russians in the former Soviet republics. The platform
> promised to the restore territorial integrity of the former Soviet state, regain it former
> superpower status, recreate a strong military, and abrogate those international treaties which undermined Russian national interests (Zyuganov, 1996a).

And (I recall) the West turning a (relatively) blind eye to Yeltsin less than democratic [means](https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=3PJuIVIZ72k) of subduing the parliamentary opposition for that very reason. Etc. Russia was never really convincing as having abandoned its Soviet ways completely, to quite a number of observers, particularly those from Eastern European countries. Their cooperation with the West on Yugoslavia was doubled by attempts to subvert the process too--Russian paratroopers on Pristina airport etc. Despite the Russian rhetoric on NATO expansion as if it happens by some centralized force, those Eastern European countries all *applied* to join, just in case the wind started to blow in a different direction in Moscow. [E.g.](https://inkstickmedia.com/albright-was-right-about-nato-expansion/)

> “When we were a candidate country, I often heard the phrase: ‘Russia is not going to be happy if the Baltic countries become members of NATO,’” said former PresidentVaira Vike-Freiberga of Latvia, another woman who, like [M.] Albright, had her perspectives on foreign policy shaped by experiences as a World War II refugee. Often standing out as one of the only women in the room, Vike-Freiberga led her country to NATO accession in 2004 as Putin was consolidating his power across the border. “President [Jacques] Chirac of France told me: ‘You should not be fooling with the mustache of the bear, you shouldn’t annoy him.’ I said, ‘No, Mr. President, but we do not want to be eaten by the bear, either.’ That is the point.”

And if you want to go back to Poland's [1999] NATO admission speech, their  [position](https://www.nato.int/docu/speech/1999/s990312d.htm) (as exemplified here by their MFA Bronislaw Geremek) was not that different, albeit the threat of external force was only mentioned in historical, but rather concrete terms...

> For the people of Poland, the Cold War, which forcibly excluded our country from the West, ends with our entry to NATO. Poland, as member of the most powerful alliance, bringing together democratic nations of Western Europe and North America, joins the vital process of bridging old divisions and contributes to the security and stability in Europe. [...]
>
> The nations, who join this community today, were denied those values until 1989. On the streets of Budapest in 1956, Prague in 1968 and Gdansk in 1970 and 1981 they paid a heavy price. They have proved their democratic credentials, which give them the right to be here today.

Why the West agreed is a somewhat different question, which is honestly a bit difficult to retell concisely. In Bush's time, when the major expansion happened, he was hemmed in by Iraq war policy and looking for allies beyond the traditional Western Europe which wasn't all that supportive (see the fabled "you forgot Poland" in the Bush-Kerry presidential debate). That stuff has been derided, but there [have been](https://www.files.ethz.ch/isn/120141/2003_US_Poland_E.pdf) more serious US positions around that time why the US wanted allies further east.

As for the Western EU capitals, I think it would have been politically difficult for them to agree to expanding the EU but to oppose expanding NATO, especially since the EU treaty has a common defense clause too. Such a stance would have probably come across as naked anti-Americanism. Even though some German press [declared](https://www.jstor.org/stable/25779521) Poland a "nation of thieves" and a Trojan horse of the US with respect to Iraq... But that only emphasizes why these Eastern European countries saw the US [and thus NATO] as the true guarantor of their security. The Western Europeans were seen as less reliable and possibly even conflicted on economic matters, like Russian gas etc.

And looking back at one of Albright's [speeches](https://1997-2001.state.gov/statements/970423.html) (from 1997) that angle (of US being the real deal in terms of security guarantees) is emphasized, albeit to a US audience:

> Many organizations are doing their part to assure the prosperity and security of Europe. The European Union is expanding. The OSCE is promoting democracy and helping to resolve conflicts from the Caucasus to the Balkans. Many of the new market democracies are joining the World Trade Organization and the OECD.
>
> But NATO is taking the lead, just as it has for the past half century. NATO is still the anchor of our engagement in Europe, the only organization in Europe with real military might, the only one capable of providing the confidence and security upon which our other goals depend.

One other worthwhile point she brings up is that during the process/negotiations of joining candidate countries were more or less compelled to solve many/most of the their outstanding issues... peacefully.

> Just the prospect of enlargement has given central and eastern Europe greater stability than it has seen in this century. Old disputes between Poland and Lithuania, Poland and Ukraine, Hungary and Romania, Italy and Slovenia, Germany and the Czech Republic are melting away as nations align themselves with NATO. Democratic reforms are advancing. Country after country has made sure soldiers take orders from civilians. These nations are fixing exactly the problems that could have led to future Bosnias.

And finally, she does get to the "historical injustice" angle that we saw in the Polish speech too, albeit this just the third leg of her argument to a US audience.

> The third reason, Mr. Chairman, as I suggested, is to right the wrongs of the past. If we don't enlarge NATO, we will be validating the dividing line Stalin imposed in 1945 and that two generations of Americans and Europeans fought to overcome. That's conscionable. With the Cold War over, there is no moral or strategic basis for saying to the American people: "we must be allied with Europe's old democracies forever, but with Europe's new democracies never."
>
> We would begin to think in entirely new terms about what a European continent, whole and free, would look like, and what our relationship with Russia and other key states on such a continent would be.

And the Clinton-Yeltsin [discussion](https://nsarchive.gwu.edu/document/27172-doc-18-memorandum-conversation-between-president-clinton-and-president-yeltsin) in the Kremlin from May 10, 1995 is actually not too far from a combination of the above: Clinton promises (p. 7) that Russia won't be excluded from consideration for NATO membership (at some point), but invites Russia to sign the Partnership for Peace first and consider a "special relationship" (which I'm guessing later became the 1997 agreement). Yeltsin asks for any NATO expansion to be postponed preferably until 2000, but at least for two years. Clinton then lays out his reasons for NATO expansion.

> WJC: Our goal is for the U.S. to stay in Europe and promote a unified, integrated Europe. I propose the following:
> [...] that there be a role for Russia in PFP and a clear statement from the U.S. that Russia should not be excluded from NATO membership. [...] But you have to walk through the doors that we open for you. That's why I've urged you to sign the,PFP documents and launch the NATO-Russia dialogue.

Clinton also mentioned a "post-COCOM" deal and G-7 membership (i.e. dangles some carrots) in the context of "greater integration of Russia into other international institutions".

> BNY: [After a long pause] But, Bill, what is involved here besides a a strategic issue is that there's an overlay of political problems~-this year the parliamentary elections, next year the presidential ones. One false move now could ruin everything. So please postpone this issue--if not until 2000, then at least for the next few-years until you and I get through our elections--so that there is only theoretical discussion about expansion. Then we can explain all this to the Eastern Europeans and the Central Europeans; we'll tell them that the time will come for expansion later.
>
> I've got to tell you, my position heading into the 1996 elections is not exactly brilliant. [...] But let's postpone NATO expansion for a year and a half or two years. There's no need to rile the situation up before the elections. [...]
>
> WJC: But you've raised political forces, so let's talk about those. You described what you are facing in 1996. Let me tell you about my situation. I face a difficult campaign, but I have a reasonable chance. **The Republicans are pushing NATO expansion. Wisconsin, Illinois and Ohio are key; they represented a big part of my majority last time --states where I won by a narrow margin. The Republicans think they can take away those states by playing on the idea of NATO expansion.** [...] You can say you don't want it speeded up --I've told you we're not going to do that --but don't ask us to slow down either, or we'll just have to keep saying no.

So yeah, Clinton played his own domestic elections card here (in return). But then gets to the Albright-y/Talbott-y stuff:

> There's a third factor. **The truth is·that for the people in the Central European countries who most want to be in NATO, it's part of being accepted by the West. But they also have security concerns. That's where it gets complicated. They trust you, Boris. They know it would be inconsistent with your interests for them to be in NATO overnight. But they are not so sure what's going to happen in Russia if you're not around, so they're conflicted**: on the one hand, they want to be in NATO in a hurry, but on the other they also want you to succeed with reform and don't want anything to happen that will prevent you from doing so.

Clinton the eggs/invites Yeltsin several more times during the conversation to join the PFP. After a break (in which he says he talked to Chernomyrdin), Yeltsin agrees (p. 12). Then he brings up G-7 cum G-8. Clinton promises to immediately talk to Kohl about it. Yeltsin then asks about FBI help with explosives tracing in re Chechnya and the like, Clinton again promises to help. Yeltsin then asks about CIS. Clinton says nobody in his administration will oppose it in any way as long membership is genuinely voluntary. Then they start to talk about COCOM relaxation; Clinton promises to make Russia a "full member" of COCOM  by 1999, but also asks that in return for Russia cut off arm sales to Iran. So it is somewhat clear that the agreement was part of "package deal", even though neither side is too openly transactional about it. Towards the end of the conversation Clinton repeats a couple of times his sales pitch about NATO expansion being a "slow, gradual, deliberate protess, consistent·with the goal of an undivided Europe" ... "and enhancing the security of all parties, including Russia". In a later brief conversation in the Hall of Facets, Clinton reminds Yeltsin than it's important for [FM] Kozyrev to sign the PFP by the next NATO meeting, so that he can deprive Bob Dole [back in Washington] of much discussion on alternative approaches, by presenting a done deal.

---

And I think it's a bit of a misconception that NATO was all *that* expansionist during Clinton's time alone. I vaguely recall more countries having applied back then, but not being quite so welcomed. For example [Romania](https://www.mae.ro/en/node/2131?page=2) was sort of put on a waiting list:

> July 1997 - NATO holds its "enlargement" summit in Madrid; the Alliance decides to invite the Czech Republic, Hungary and Poland to join the Alliance; the final communiqué confirms that the process of enlargement continues; the text nominates Romania among the candidate countries which have made significant progress in fulfilling the NATO membership criteria.

Romania and six other countries joined during Bush's presidency, i.e. in 2004. Only three countries joined during Clinton's. I haven't quite summed up the areas of the 1999 vs 2004 waves, but on [first glance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:History_of_NATO_enlargement.svg) they look similar.

---

I also think it was not all that

> clear that extending NATO would change the situation and bring back the confrontation

(as the question says) because Russia and NATO back in 1996-97 had [agreed](https://www.nato.int/cps/su/natohq/official_texts_25468.htm) to the “Founding Act" (on Mutual Relations, Cooperation and Security between NATO and the Russian Federation signed in Paris), in which NATO countries promised not to deploy nuclear weapons or "permanent stationing of substantial combat forces" in the new NATO members.
Eventually, those NATO promises became insufficient for subsequent Russian governments (specifically Putin's--he demanded a rollback to a pre-1997 situation sometime in late 2021). But it was hardly clear to participants in the 1997 agreement that those restrictions on NATO force deployments would be seen as insufficient (much) later by a subsequent Russian governments.

It's true however that even Yeltsin equivocated on NATO expansion, changing his level of stated opposition. In particular, the issue was electorally toxic for him back home. So, the Clinton administration postponed any concrete steps until after the 1996 election in Russia. On other hand, even Yeltsin recognized [e.g. to Clinton at Hyde Park in 1995] that the Polish American Congress was exercising pressure in the opposite direction in the US elections. I recall one Canadian diplomat claiming to me that this was a major factor in US support, but that kind of claim is somewhat hard to substantiate. But one book [kind of supports that](https://books.google.com/books?id=RW_imaOZgq8C&pg=PA100):

> Of the ten districts with the highest concentration of Polish Americans, Ronald Reagan had won seven in 1980 and nine in 1984. Although [H. W.] Bush also won nine of these in his race with Michael Dukakis in 1988, Clinton had take seven of these districts in the 1992 campaign. (And he would go on to defeat Bob Dole in eight of them.)

Somewhat counterbalancing that though:

> A poll taken in 1996 showed that while Americans of central and eastern European descent did not show support for NATO enlargement at higher levels than other Americans (who were generally favorable), they felt more strongly about the issue and they were also significantly more likely to be aware of it.

The book also recounts how Bob Dole's tried to court that vote by "naming [country] names and setting a date" for the enlargement, and meeting with Lech Walesa. So, yeah, there was the US domestic lobbying aspect at least for Poland, but it's probably hard to pin too much on that angle for the other countries that joined (later or in the same wave). It's also worth noting that not all Republicans tried to "one up" Clinton on this. And neither were all Democrats convinced. Sam Nunn opposed "rapid NATO enlargement" for fear of jeopardizing nuclear disarmament agreements with Russia, and voted against one relevant bill, somewhat famously changing his vote to nay during the roll call.

[Support](https://transatlanticrelations.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/16-Rosner.pdf) for enlargement was ultimately a fairly broad affair in 1997-98 (vote was 80-19 in the Senate, with 67 required to pass):

> Although support for NATO’s enlargement was broad, it was comprised of what political scientist George Grayson later called a “strange bedfellows” coalition, including Republicans and Democrats, defense hawks and human rights idealists, unionists focused on the brave actions of Poland’s Solidarity, and business leaders focused on the lure of new markets in Central Europe.

The people entrusted with making this law pass the Senate were also tasked to convince that it would

> not come at the expense of other U.S. interests, including constructive relations with Russia. Clinton had staked a good deal on building closer ties to Russia and President Boris Yeltsin. A win on NATO enlargement would be undermined if pursued in a way that needlessly poisoned that relationship.

And in particular:

> The [NATO-Russia] Founding Act was positive enough toward Moscow that it reduced anxieties (mostly among Democrats) that NATO enlargement would antagonize Moscow. But it also had enough red lines between Russia and NATO’s own decision-making that it minimized concerns (mostly among Republicans) that NATO was giving Russia any kind of vote or veto.

So back then (late 1990s), in the US at least, the expansion was not seen a posing that kind of "clear" danger (by most US decision-makers), given these other mitigating efforts the US/NATO was undertaking vis-a-vis of Russia.

---

What I personally find more surprising is that the second, 2004 expansion [was](https://www.armscontrol.org/act/2003-06/press-releases/senate-approves-nato-expansion-seven-new-members) voted 96-0 in the US Senate, despite involving more countries that were closer to Russia, and which had longer borders with it, than in the 1999 wave. Pretty much every [article](https://www.nytimes.com/2003/05/08/international/worldspecial/senate-votes-unanimously-to-approve-expansion-of.html) I've read on that latter vote mentions that a number of those countries stood by the US on the Iraq decision... and some of the new candidates had helped the US logistically or militarily (e.g. Romania and Bulgaria). Unfortunately, it is difficult to research whether the amount of verbal opposition/protest from Russia's leadership against NATO expansion had gone up or down in that 1999-2003 time frame. For what it's worth, the NYT wrote in their 2003 coverage of that Senate vote:

> But past Russian opposition to NATO expansion has faded under President Vladimir V. Putin, who has carved out for his country a consultative role with the alliance.

So, at least some of the US opinion makers were of that view. (And the consultative thing seems to refer to the 2002-established [NATO-Russia Council](https://www.nato.int/nrc-website/en/about/index.html).)

Comment: "As for the Western EU capitals, I think it would have been politically difficult for them to agree to expanding EU but to oppose expanding NATO." But EU membership without the NATO one works as can be seen on the example of Austria. An other 2 examples were Sweden and Finland.

Comment: @convert: yes, but those have been domestic decisions. Those didn't apply and [were not] turned down. Although with Turkey lately, who knows if they can be bought off wrt Finland and Sweden.

Comment: @convert: actually not entirely domestic, as it turns out. Austria promised to not join any military alliance in a 1955 treaty with the USSR, as a condition for Soviet troop withdrawal. https://www.thelocal.at/20220304/explained-why-isnt-austria-in-nato/

Comment: Ideas and (mostly failed) projects for a European defence have existed in EU circles for a long time but the current mutual defence clause was introduced with the treaty of Lisbon (and I don't think it was in the Treaty establishing a constitution for Europe) so it's a bit anachronistic to invoke it there.

Answer (score 17):

An often neglected reason for the fundamental change in the NATO-Russian relationship is the [civil war in Yugoslavia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yugoslav_Wars) Before that, there were ideas to create a pan-European security system that would include Russia, for example by letting [Russia join NATO.](https://www.nytimes.com/1991/12/21/world/soviet-disarray-yeltsin-says-russia-seeks-to-join-nato.html) One often-quoted source from this time is German foreign minister Hans-Dietrich Genscher, who [reportedly said this](https://nsarchive.gwu.edu/document/16112-document-01-u-s-embassy-bonn-confidential-cable) in a speech in Tutzing, Bavaria on Jan 31st, 1990:

> NATO should rule out an ‘expansion of its territory towards the east, i.e. moving it closer to the Soviet borders.’”

In the same speech he also called for bigger involvement of the [CSCE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conference_on_Security_and_Co-operation_in_Europe) in the construction of the future security framework in Europe, which surely would have come at the expense of US influence.

Then NATO general secretary Manfred Wörner shared this position. In a [speech on May 17th 1990,](https://www.nato.int/docu/speech/1990/s900517a_e.htm) he emphasized the role of the CSCE in assuring everybody that Russian security interests would not be jeopardized. This is the speech Vladimir Putin referred to [in Munich in 2007,](https://is.muni.cz/th/xlghl/DP_Fillinger_Speeches.pdf) when he complained about promises being broken by NATO.

So, in the early 90s, NATO expansion was not considered an imminent or even desirable thing.

What changed this? The [siege of Sarajevo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Sarajevo) started to show differences between Russian and Western views of the conflict. While the Western public was shocked by the atrocities committed by all sides in the war, Russia [vetoed](https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/politics/1994/12/03/russia-casts-veto-in-1st-split-on-bosnia/5e75adb0-f98b-4280-bab3-b306f132975c/) actions in the UN security council. In the West, the public grew increasingly frustrated with the Russian blockade. After [the Srebrenica massacre,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srebrenica_massacre) Western countries decided to [act unilaterally,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Deliberate_Force) and repeated this [a few years later.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_bombing_of_Yugoslavia)

Russia viewed this as a huge insult. Prof. Yuriy Davydov writes in his study ["Should Russia join NATO?"](https://www.nato.int/acad/fellow/98-00/davydov.pdf) in 2000:

> The NATO military action in Yugoslavia was used by the national patriots for
> carrying out the most massive anti-Western campaign in Russia since the cold war. It has
> become the first step to V. Putin’s victory in the presidential elections 2000.

In the same year, Alexei Arbatov published his study ["The Transformation of Russian Military Doctrine: Lessons Learned from Kosovo and Chechnya"](https://www.marshallcenter.org/de/node/1409#toc-russian-federation-military-doctrine) Arbatov argues that the NATO bombings led to a change in Russian military doctrine:

> Russia has learned many lessons from Kosovo.  Above all, the end justifies the means. The use of force is the most efficient problem solver, if applied decisively and massively. Negotiations are of dubious value and should be used as a cover for military action. International law and human suffering are of secondary significance in achieving the goal. Massive devastation and collateral fatalities among the civilian population are acceptable in order to limit one’s own casualties. Foreign public opinion and the position of Western governments are to be discounted if Russian interests are at stake. The key to success is a concentrated campaign in the mass media and tight control over information about the war.

In Eastern Europe this change in the Russian position towards the West was noticed immediately. Just like Sweden and Finland today, countries quickly started to reevaluate their security needs and apply for NATO membership. In the United States, this was met with support. On July 23rd 1996, a Republican-led House of Representatives passed [HR3564,](https://www.congress.gov/bill/104th-congress/house-bill/3564) calling for NATO membership of three countries

> Poland, Hungary, and the Czech Republic

but also

> in order to promote security in Estonia, Latvia, Lithuania, Slovenia, Slovakia, Bulgaria, Romania, Albania, Moldova, and Ukraine: (1) the United States should continue to support the full and active participation of these countries in activities that will qualify them for NATO membership

In 1997, NATO began to negotiate with Poland, the Czech Republic and Hungary, and on March 12th 1999, the three countries [officially joined NATO.](https://nsarchive.gwu.edu/document/16112-document-01-u-s-embassy-bonn-confidential-cable)

So, in short: Russia and the Western countries have fundamentally different ideas of how Europe's future security architecture should look like. Russia sees NATO as a tool for US imperialism, and is perfectly fine with that, as long as the West is ok with Russian imperialism. Western Europeans see NATO as a purely defensive alliance, and notice Russia's habit of attacking non-NATO countries. These views are irreconcilable, and it took the crises of the 1990, in particular the war in Yugoslavia, to make this visible.

Answer (score 11):

> So at the begin of the 90s the Cold War was officially over no Warsaw Pact and even no USSR was there to threaten NATO. The new Russian government was relative pro-western, the most pro-western government in Russia ever. There was no antiwestern propaganda in Russian media, sometimes even the opposite was the case.

Probably there were no threat to then NATO countries. How about threat to those, that applied to NATO at that time?
[Russia intervened in Georgia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgian_Civil_War), [supported separation of Abkhazia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_in_Abkhazia_(1992%E2%80%931993)), resulting in [ethnic cleansing of Georgians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethnic_cleansing_of_Georgians_in_Sukhumi). No one was held responsible for those atrocities. Later Russia supported [Transnistria separation from Moldova](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transnistria_War).
Few years later world could observe [first Chechen war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Chechen_War), with [more war crimes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samashki_massacre) committed by Russian forces. Again - no one was held responsible. In 1999 those, who were responsible for [yet another massacre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkhan-Yurt_massacre) [got awarded.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vladimir_Shamanov#Controversies)
Russian troops [left Poland in 1993](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_Group_of_Forces). Should Poland, Czech Republic, Slovakia and Baltic states feel safe with such a neighbor? Was it reasonable for them to apply to NATO? Those, who are responsible for American war crimes, [are sometimes prosecuted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%E1%BB%B9_Lai_massacre#Court_martial), Russian perpetrators - never.

Comment: Exactly. Countries like Poland (which has had a _whole history_ of trouble involving Russia) and Czechia (whose previous attempt at diverging a little from the USSR earned them a Soviet invasion and two decades of occupation) obviously had little reason to believe Russia was going to leave them alone this time. They were highly motivated to build close ties with the West as quickly as possible. Had NATO refused to accept them, it would have caused massive disillusionment and damaged relations for a long time to come.

Comment: @TooTea But that countries had made similar experiences with Germany.

Comment: @convert Not in last 75 years.

Comment: Czech Republic is not a neighbor to Russia. It's quite far away from Russia. Slovakia too. Poland has a border with the Russian Kaliningrad exclave but it's laughable to expect a military invasion from it. Also, the war in Chechnya was an internal war within Russian borders, it was not  a case of Russia's attack on another country.

Comment: @CITBL "Poland has a border with the Russian Kaliningrad exclave but it's laughable to expect a military invasion from it." Well, would you expect a Russian military invasion from Belarus? It happened on February 2022 - attack targeting Kyiv. In 1999 it wasn't clear if Ukraine would go Belarusian way, or not. That makes quite a long vulnerable border for Poland and Slovakia. Should Czech Republic feel safe separated from that border by Slovakia?

Comment: @TadeuszKopec So Chechia has border with Slovakia, which has border with Ukraine which has border with Belarus and Russia and therefore Chechia should feel unsafe. Right? If we think that way then Portugal should feel unsafe too. Don't you think it sounds a little paranoid? (Even if we put away the question of Russia managing to go all the way through Ukraine and Slovakia). Not to mention WHY would it attack Chechia? What for???? Just because?

Comment: @CITBL Russia had no problem to travel through GDR, Poland and Hungary to invade Czechoslovakia in 1968. In 2022 it had no problem to travel through Belarus. In 1999 you could not tell, if Ukraine would be as cooperative as Belarus is now. And why invade? Because Russia is an evil colonialist empire. If you have doubts seeing their invasion on Ukraine, nothing can convince you.

Comment: @TadeuszKopec No. You don't understand why the USSR conducted their "special military operation" in Czechoslovakia in 1968. It's because the USSR was governed by radical left wing Marxists who really believed in Marx gospels, world proletarian revolution. Whose goal was to spread communism. When they got an opportunity after the war to install communism in Europe's East, they did it. And when someone wanted to get rid of communism (like Czechoslvakia) they saw that as a threat. That's why 1968 happened. Now Russia is not communist. The reasons of the war in Ukraine can't be applied to Czechia

Comment: @TadeuszKopec The USSR had no problem to travel through GDR, Poland and Hungary to Czechoslovakia because those countries was members of the Warsaw Pact

Comment: @CITBL And Ukraine was one of the founders of [Commonwealth of Independent States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commonwealth_of_Independent_States). If they decided to participate more, traveling through Ukraine would be as difficult, as now is traveling through Belarus.

Comment: Commonwealth of independent states is not a military alliance (unlike the Warsaw pact). Ukraine has not been a member of Commonwealth of independent states when Russia started the war. And Slovakia too is not a member of it. Also, equating Commonwealth of independent states with the Warsaw Pact is either ignorant or  dishonest

Comment: @CITBL which war? The question is about extending NATO in 1990s.

Comment: Ok. Commonwealth of Independent States (CIS) is not a military alliance.  Russia does not have the same power in CIS as it had in the Warsaw Pact.  Ukraine has never been a member of CIS. It was "Associate State". Russia was not a threat to Czechia in 1996 and it isn't now.

Answer (score 9):

I think calling it extending still shapes the question in a somewhat wrong light. NATO has a charter with rules that regulate how new members can join. Countries can decide on their own if they want to apply for membership. These rules were not changed in a major way in the 90s. The only thing that was different in the 90s compared to the 80s or the 2000s is that **NATO got a lot more applications for membership**. The criteria to accept an application haven't changed a lot and so a time period with a lot of applications comes with a lot of new members.

Comment: "calling it expanding" Where did I called it expanding? I even explicitly worte, that I am not using this term.

Comment: @convert Sorry, misquoted you. I will edit to the word extending that you used. My point was more that this still sounds like an active thing that NATO does, whereas my point is that to a large degree it is passive, other countries apply to NATO.

Comment: But NATO has an active role, as it not just about countries wanting to join NATO, but also about the ones who are already members.

Answer (score 4):

#### Active intervention in case of attacks

One of the underlying principles of NATO is that a military attack on one country is an attack on all, and will be responded to militarily.  Since the total military strength of all NATO countries was greater than any single country (including any single NATO country), this gave a guarantee of military protection in the event of any future conflicts, from any possible source.

If other similar treaty organisations had existed, perhaps these countries would have chosen to join those organisations instead.  However no other such arrangement existed between sovereign nations.

Note that there was no need to speculate about the source of any future attack.  In fact the first time the principle of mutual defense was invoked was [in the wake of the 9/11 attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NATO_operations), with an enemy who could not possibly have been foreseen when the USA and other countries first formed NATO in 1949.  Nevertheless, the principle still applied.  In the case of the ex-Soviet countries, the possibility of disputes amongst each other [was very real](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-Soviet_conflicts).  It is notable though that in spite of all the conflicts within the Caucasus region, none of them have involved border conflicts with Turkey (a NATO member).

Answer (score 2):

Not the only reason by any means, but one can't ignore how the behind-the-scenes lobbying in Washington went [at the time](https://www.nytimes.com/1998/03/30/world/arms-contractors-spend-to-promote-an-expanded-nato.html):

> The arms makers quickly latched onto the idea and over time helped the Administration sell it. ''It's not a case of whispering in Clinton's ear and saying, 'Expand NATO because we want to sell arms,' '' said William D. Hartung, author of a recent report for the World Policy Institute, a private arms control group that opposes expansion. ''But they've become one of Clinton's most energetic allies in promoting it.''
>
> The chief vehicle of support for NATO expansion is a group called the
> U.S. Committee to Expand NATO, which is backed by the arms industry.
> The committee president is Bruce L. Jackson, who is also director of
> strategic planning for Lockheed. Corporate sponsors are also
> supporting ethnic groups that have championed NATO membership for
> their native countries

The incentives were strong:

> Under NATO rules, new members are required to upgrade their militaries and make them compatible with those of the Western military alliance, which oversees the most sophisticated -- and expensive -- weapons and communication systems in the world. The companies that win the contracts to provide that ''inter-operability'' to the aging Soviet-made systems in Eastern Europe will benefit enormously from NATO's eastward expansion.
>
> Thus the sums spent on lobbying and for campaign contributions are
> relatively small compared with the potential benefits in the new
> markets provided by a larger NATO, particularly from the sale of
> big-ticket items like fighter aircraft

Answer (score 0):

Baltic states have made I think the correct prediction that without NATO, the they would even not be the next after Ukraine now, but would have been the **first**. These countries have done all they could to join this defensive organization, with significant support from the local population.

In 1991 one "relatively pro-western" country arrived with tanks to Lithuanian capital, killed 13 unarmed civilians, took over TV tower and broadcasted for a couple of weeks extensive explanations to Lithuanians (who were all fluent in Russian to understand) about who they really are. The push towards NATO by [these events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/January_Events_(Lithuania)) was such that no local propaganda could ever achieve, forget. Latvia received a [comparable treatment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Barricades).

Human memory lasts for many decades and is passed between generations. It cannot be washed away with the hose of propaganda that easily. Once the shift backwards happened - can happen again. And it did as we see.

Comment: At that time Lithuania was part of USSR, so USSR did exactly the same what Ukraine is doing in Lugansk and Donetsk.

Comment: Have it been any historical records about Ukraine illegally occupying Lugansk and Donetsk, previously sovereign countries, somewhere around 1940? I am not aware of any. Baltic states were never legally "part of USSR", unless you count the Molotov–Ribbentrop pact as valid.

Comment: The questions asking for reasons of NATO itself and not the countries that joined. The baltic states alway hated Russia like the most countries in East Europe, so this was the main reason to join.

Comment: NATO grows because someone wants to join it, or what it could be any other reasons?

Comment: But some years ago Brasil wanted to join and was refused, so it defenetly not just about countries wanting to join.

Comment: New members are accepted if existing NATO members have nothing against. Was OK for them for some reason.

Comment: Also my main point was that it´s abit ufair to blaim Russia for what USSR has done. The new russian government has recognized the independance of Baltic states.

Comment: I agree this was probably not very fair, and I indeed do not remember anybody pointing this out at the time. Somehow it was assumed that apart Russia, no any other Soviet state has any influence on that the Soviet Union is doing.

Comment: Also Yelzin has recognized the independance of the Baltic states just a few days after the events in Vilnjus when USSR was still existing.

Comment: That's what the Baltic states say. As for the military folks themselves who were ordered to take over the TV tower, they were given blank ammunition, a fact well known long before the start of the Russian-Ukrainian war. Further, not 13 folks who were killed, but 14, and not civilians, but the members of the Alpha group who were ordered to take over the TV tower and not given proper ammo.

Comment: There were large funerals later for these victims where many thousands attended, and streets are now named after them. We know who they were. A 23 year girl has been killed, Loreta Asanavičiūtė. 52 wounded by bullets. One of yours has been killed, Viktor Šatckich, the bullet fits the riffles used by the attacking Russian group. Some say it may be for refusal to follow the military order to attack civilians. But I also watched the "Nachi" propaganda movie and fully understand that are you talking about.

Answer (score -1):

No-one expected that the Soviet Union would fall apart peacefully. No-one.

After the failure of the state capitalism of the Eastern bloc, there was a hunger from the former Eastern bloc to engage with democracy and Western capitalism. This should have been a golden opportunity for the West to create a new international order. However, whilst there was Western aid targetted at Czechoslovakia and Poland for instance, no such aid was forthcoming for Russia. Russia had to be punished even though the cold war was over. It's no surprise then its version of capitalism was seen as a kleptocracy.

Given that the Soviet Union was a nuclear state with the second highest stockpile of nuclear weapons it is a missed opportunity of epic proportions. To show good faith, the West ought to have abandoned NATO, it had served its purpose. It ought to have created a new security architecture encompassing Russia and the former Eastern bloc. Instead, it continued with NATO and despite the verbal agreements given to Gorbachev they extended NATO into the former eastern bloc.

Given that it had taken thirty years before Russia lost its patience, I think its intentions and goodwill were sincere. The US, as they proved in Iraq and Afghanistan simply lacks any self awareness. This is the view of most of the global south who simply do not buy into the narrative of the US as being the good guys.

Comment: This reads more like a rant of the US than an analysis. Sure, history could have gone differently, but that's always the case. It's also Russia that decided against this historic chance. It will take a bit more time until Russians will realize that one cannot live from nuclear weapons alone.

Comment: @Trilarion: Just because you do not agree or lile my analysis of the politics of the situation does not make it a rant. I am not indulging in alternative history, that is a genre of fiction. It's not Russia that decided against this historic opportunity but the West as I said in my post.

Comment: @MoziburUllah Trilarion is right, its a rant. If not a rant, then an attempt at propaganda. You're going to have to provide some supporting arguments or citations for a lot of claims here. Abandon NATO? Its been hailed as a benefit since '91. You claim no such help was given to Russia, did you forget the Lend Lease that saved Russia from the Germans, and how was that repaid? It was over 90% written off. The only argument for a new security apparatus to replace NATO is because Russia refuses to join an organization, others must join them. So create a new one with them as a leader or bust.

Comment: @David S: It's not a rant and nor is it propanganda. The last but one ambassador to the Soviet Union, Jack Matlock actually proposed a new security architecture covering the old Soviet Union and the West and did important work on this as well as testifying in front of Congress that without this the flashpoints of the old security architecture would be Georgia and Ukraine and this has been proved to be the case. It has also be noted in plenty of sources that Gorbachev's red lines was the non-expansion of NATO into Eastern Europe. And it need no references to note that this non-formal ...

Comment: @David S: ... has not been kept to.